# On the strength of sufficient condition for complex differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f:A \to \Bbb C$, $A \subseteq \Bbb C$, be a function with the form $f=u+iv$, The very familiar sufficient condition for differentiability is the continuity of partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ in addition with Cauchy-Riemann equations.

But,

i. Considering $f$ as a function from a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$, we need only the continuity of one of the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ for the differentiability (Apostol, Mathematical Analysis, Theorem 12.11).

ii. Also, $f$ is complex differentiable if and only if $f$ is real differentiable in addition to Cauchy-Riemann equations.

From the above premises (i and ii), I can conclude that the continuity of one of the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ besides Cauchy-Riemann equations is sufficient for the complex differentiability of $f$.

I feel something is missing since the conventional sufficient condition is slightly different.

Any analytical error committed in the deduction?

Comment: Misread your quesiton. Anyone this part may help : I think of CR simply as a constraint relation between the partials of the real and imaginary part of the function , that means, given a certain real part, the CR restricts what the imaginary part it could be paired with such that you get a Complex differentiable function.

Comment: Do you mean something like $u_x=v_y$ is continuous but $u_y=-v_x$ is not required to be continuous?

Comment: Exactly, that's my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the "traditional" theorem is

- If $f$ is continuously partially differentiable at $z_0$ and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z_0$, then $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$.

This is a consequence of the following two ingredients:

1. $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ if and only if it is real differentiable at $z_0$ and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z_0$.
2. If $f$ is continuously partially differentiable at $z_0$, then it is real differentiable at $z_0$.

As you noticed, the assumption of 2. can be weakened:

3. If $f$ is partially differentiable at $z_0$ and one of the partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y$ exists in a neigborhood of $z_0$ and is continuous at $z_0$, then $f$ is real differentiable at $z_0$.

This allows to formulate a variant of the above theorem with a slightly weaker assumption (as you have done in your question).

However, the weaker assumption in 3. is not really relevant. In practice we are interested in *holomorphic* functions $f : U \to \mathbb C$ on a region $U \subset \mathbb  C$, i.e. functions which are complex differentiable at all points of $U$. Even without using 3. we get the following theorem:

- Let $f = u  + iv$ be partially differentiable in all points of $U$ (that is, $u_x = \partial u/\partial x, u_y = \partial u/\partial y, v_x = \partial v/\partial x, v_y = \partial v/\partial y$ exist in all points of $U$) such that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at all points of $U$. Assume that in each point $z_0 \in U$ one of the following conditions is satisfied:
  (a) $u_x, v_x$ are continuous at $z_0$.
  (b) $u_y, v_y$ are continuous at $z_0$.
  (c) $u_x, u_y$ are continuous at $z_0$.
  (d) $v_x, v_y$ are continuous at $z_0$.
  Then $f$ is holomorphic.

In fact, under the above assumptions the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that **both** $u,v$  have continuous partial derivatives at each point of $U$ - and this is the traditional assumption.

Comment: Sir, I think without mentioning a region $U$ , this wont work, I mean the equivalent condition is not a local phenomenon, right?

Comment: As I have $f(z)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin (\frac{1}{x})&x\neq 0\\ 0&x=0,\end{cases}$ for $z=x+iy$.

Comment: @RIYASUDHEENTK Correct. If you consider a single poimt $z_0$, you get a strictly weaker sufficient condition. You do not even need to assume that the partial derivatives of $v$ (above notation) exist in a neigborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: Thnks a lot....

Comment: @PaulFrost your weakened condition (3) requires the existence of partial derivatives of one of the components of $f$ and the continuity of partial derivatives of other component. Instead, the Theorem 12.11 [(page no: 357)](http://webpages.iust.ac.ir/amtehrani/files/Addison%20Wesley%20-%20Mathematical%20Analysis%20_%20Apostol%20%285Th%20Ed%29%20%281981%29.pdf) requires the existence one of the partial derivatives of $f$ itself, and the continuity of other partial derivative. Are they coincides in the conclusion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MessiLio You discovered an error in my answer. I corrected it.